# I want to get data from text key inside choices I'm stuck for an hour can anyone help me out

Tags: python, json

Need to get data from text key Been trying with
it is not working and giving error :list indices must be integers or slices, not str

```
resp = json.loads(str(result)) 
resp['choices']['text]
```

JSON:

```
{
  "choices": [
    {
      "finason": "stop",
      "index": 0,
      "logprobs": null,
      "text": "hihihiii"
    }
  ],
  "created": 1595021770,
  "id": "cmp pvu4OUC5Qbh4C",
  "model": " 2020-05-03",
  "object": "tex tion"
}
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`resp['choices']` is a list so you will need integers index to access its element:

```
resp = json.loads(str(result))
resp['choices'][0]['text']
```